# laravel 5 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ExceptionMakeCommand' not found

Tags: php, laravel

The following command throws `FatalException`, as seen below:

```
php artisan migrate
```

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ExceptionMakeCommand' not found

My code:

```
public function up() {
 Schema::create('newsletter', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('newsletter_id');
  $table->string('email', 255)->nullable();
  $table->timestamps(); });
 } /** * Reverse the migrations. * * @return void */

 public function down() {
  Schema::dropIfExists('newsletter');
 }
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: What migration did you make last? Paste the code!

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('newsletter', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('newsletter_id');
            $table->string('email', 255)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('newsletter');
    }`

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the code to the question and format it correctly.

Comment: @Sand, thanks to correct me. please need help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue on laravel configuration. Try the following commands,

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: when I run any artisan command I got this below,
`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]               
  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ExceptionMakeCommand' not found  
`

Comment: Try removing vendor directory and composer.lock file and then try executing `composer install`

Comment: I tried, But not working. Then I install new version.. any way thanks.. :(